# Formatting API Array Output

Tags: php, html, arrays, api

I am new to API integration and PHP. I recently integrated a VIN decoder API into my app. If a vehicle's VIN is entered into the input bar and <kbd>submit</kbd> is selected, the API will retrieve relevant data concerning that vehicle. For example, if I enter `WAUBFAFL6FA058452` and click <kbd>submit</kbd>, I will receive data that this VIN belongs to a 2015 Audi A4 Sedan.

The issue I am running into is that not all data fields return with data. For instance, `WAUBFAFL6FA058452` returns:

```
Make: Audi
Model: A4
ModelYear: 2015
VehicleType: PASSENGER CAR
Series: Premium quattro
```

However, about twenty or so other fields are returned blank such as:

```
DriveType:
DynamicBrakeSupport:
EDR:
ESC:
EVDriveUnit:
ElectrificationLevel:
```

How can I create an `if` statement within my PHP that only returns categories that contain data? In other words, categories such as `Make` would be visible to the user but categories such as `DriveType` won't be. Visibility of categories is dependent on that category having data. This needs to be structured as an `if` statement because some VINs carry more data than others and vice versa.

I have tried for about an hour now, and have been unsuccessful.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>VIN Decoder API Test</title>

<style type="text/css">
input,button {width: 200px;display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
button {width: 100px;background-color: darkgray;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <form action="processvin.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" id="b12" placeholder="Enter VIN" name="b12" maxlength="100"/>
    <br>
    <button id="submit_btn">Submit</button>

  </form>

  <br>
  <br>

</body>
</html>
```

processvin.php

```
<?php

$vin = $_POST["b12"];

if ($vin) {
    $postdata = http_build_query([
            'format' => 'json',
            'data' => $vin
        ]
    );
    $opts = [
        'http' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $postdata
        ]
    ];

    $apiURL = "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/";
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $fp = fopen($apiURL, 'rb', false, $context);
    $line_of_text = fgets($fp);
    $json = json_decode($line_of_text, true);
    fclose($fp);

    foreach ($json['Results'][0] as $k => $v){
      $results .= ($k).": ".($v).'<br />';
    }
    echo $results;
  }
    else {
    echo 'No Vin Inputted';
    }

?>
```

Any help, suggestions, pointers, etc will not be taken for granted! Thanks so much!

Comment: In foreach ... `if (!empty($v)) { $results .= ($k).": ".($v).'<br />';}`

Comment: @RiggsFolly this works great. `!empty` is a false statement, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try several different types of tests that may work *empty($v), isset($v),  is_null($v), or strcmp($v, "")*. Since this is a JSON it is most likely that blank values in $v are stored as a "". Therefor you should probably start with empty().  But try it and see.

```
foreach ($json['Results'][0] as $k => $v){
    if (!empty($v)){
         $results .= ($k).": ".($v).'<br />';
    }
}
```

This will only add results if $v is not empty.